# JS add in-line css to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, selectize.js

I'm stuck with something here:

I have a hidden div with some optional filters in a results page.

```
<div id='b-filters' class='row'>...</div>
```

Initially it is hidden with `display: none;`, when click a link it shows with some buttons and selectize combos.

The problem is here:

When div shows up, some JS, I don't know how to find out which; adds some in-line css:

```
<div id='b-filters' class='row' style='overflow: hidden; display: block;'>...</div>
```

So it is no possible to see the combos options. Using Chrome debugger I change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: visible` and it works as I'd like.

I have tried:

In my external css file (app.css)

```
#b-filters{
  ...
  overflow: visible;
  ...
}
```

But does not work, and in the same html file:

```
<head>
...
  <style>
    div#b-filters{
      overflow: visible;
    }
  </style>
</head>
...
```

But Chrome inspector always show `overflow: visible;` crossed out.

Any idea? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I took @Stephen Thomas answer, but I'd like somebody help me with the way to find out which JS is adding that in-line css.

Comment: Could you please add your JavaScript to your post?

Comment: How are you "un-hiding" the `<div>`?

Comment: Inline CSS has priority over all other css _except_ those rules marked as `!important`. If you're using jQuery, you can overwrite this with their `.css()` method.

Comment: @Waflix the js involved to show up div is Foundation js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the actual JavaScript, the only suggestion I can offer is

```
div#b-filters{
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

But if you show us your code, there is probably a more elegant way.

Comment: OMG this is just like magic! It worked, but why this is not elegant?

Comment: it may be just fine for you. OTOH, some folks might prefer to eliminate the `overflow: hidden` in the first place instead of overriding it

Comment: Some people also think using !important is bad practice, no matter what the circumstances are.

Comment: @HaukurHaf that's a big discussion topic, if it is no good to use something why it exists?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not one of those people :-)  I use !important when it's appropriate.  This is one use case where !important is useful, but perhaps it would be better to find and remove/disable the code that is adding this overflow style in the first place :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding inline CSS directly to the element, why not abstract the CSS attributes into generalized classes, then just add/remove those classes?!

```
// style.css
.hide {
   display: none;
}

// view.html
<div id="b-filters" class="row hide">...</div>

// app.js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   var el = document.querySelector('#b-filters');
   el.classList.remove('hide');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good solution, but in my case there's a lot of AngularJS (controllers and directives) involved.

Comment: That exact action (hide and show) is made with Foundation built-in js

Answer (score 0):

```
var problematicDiv = document.getElementById('b-filters');

if(problematicDiv.hasAttribute('style'))
{
    problematicDiv.removeAttribute('style');
    problematicDiv.style.display = 'block';
    problematicDiv.style.overflow = 'visible';
}
```

This 'pseudo' js code should work as eventlistener.. haven't tested though, but I think it's ok.